# Nechemiah 13 changes Hashem to Elokim

Tags: tanach, ezra-nechemya

Nechemia 13:1 reads

> בַּיּ֣וֹם הַה֗וּא נִקְרָ֛א בְּסֵ֥פֶר מֹשֶׁ֖ה בְּאָזְנֵ֣י הָעָ֑ם וְנִמְצָא֙ כָּת֣וּב בּ֔וֹ אֲ֠שֶׁר לֹא־יָב֨וֹא עַמֹּנִ֧י וּמֹאָבִ֛י בִּקְהַ֥ל הָאֱלֹהִ֖ים עַד־עוֹלָֽם

This verse quotes Devorim 23:4 but its says

> לֹֽא־יָבֹ֧א עַמּוֹנִ֛י וּמוֹאָבִ֖י בִּקְהַ֣ל יְהוָ֑ה גַּ֚ם דּ֣וֹר עֲשִׂירִ֔י לֹא־יָבֹ֥א לָהֶ֛ם בִּקְהַ֥ל יְהוָ֖ה עַד־עוֹלָֽם

Why change Hashem to Ha-Elokim?

Similarly, why does Verse 2 substitute elokeinu for Hashem elokecha.

Comment: More to the point, check out the Malbim; he usually addresses these issues.

Comment: @DannySchoemann in Nech 13:1 the Malbim doesn't speak about this.

Comment: I think that the use of "asher" could make what follows into a paraphrasing and not necessarily a direct quote so the change is just in the retelling, not a textual editing.

Comment: Does that mean Nechemiah had no specific reason for choosing Elokim over Hashem?